# Total probability law problem

Tags: conditional-probability, exponential-distribution

A startup that offers two kinds of services, $S_1$ and $S_2$. Both services follow an exponential law with $S_1$ provided, on average, within $1$ minute while $S_2$ within $2$ minutes.
$70\%$ of clients prefer $S_1$ and the remaining $30\%$ prefer $S_2$.

1. What is the probability that a client will be served in less than $2$ minutes?
2. Knowing that the services was provided in less than $2$ minutes, what is the probability that the client asked for $S_1$?

For point 1) I think it is right to use the law of total probability so let A = "the client will be served in less than 2 minutes" then $P(A) = P(A|S_1)P(S_1) + P(A|S_2)P(S_2)$. If this is correct how do I calculate/reason on what is $P(A|S_1)$? For the point 2) requires $P(A)$ (right?) so can I use conditional probability and calculate $P(S_1|A) = \frac{P(A|S_1)P(S_1)}{P(A)}$ ?

Comment: Typeset mathematical terms using MathJax. [Here's the tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Point 1)* You are correct so far. To calculate $P(A|S_i)$ note that if $X \sim exp(\lambda)$ then $E[X] = \tfrac{1}{\lambda}$ and you know the average of both $S_1$ and $S_2$.

*Point 2)* I believe you meant to type the Bayes' rule ($P(X|Y) = \frac{P(Y|X)P(X)}{P(Y)}$) but you made a mistake while typing. If that's the case you are correct again.

Comment: Thank you, ye I meant Bayes. So I've calculate the integrals (S1 is 0.86 and S2 is 0.63). By solving the integral what I find is the P(A | S1) and P(A | S2)? Assuming that what I said is correct then P(A) = 0.79 which seems reasonable. How could I find P(A | S1) to solve point 2) ?

Comment: $P(A|S_1) = 0.86$ as you said. I don't understand what you are asking to be honest.

Comment: Mm maybe I am confused, by solving the integral for S1 I find P(A|S1)? If it's correct could you explain why it's so pls

Comment: $A | S_1$ denotes the event that the client is served from service one in under 2 minutes so for any $t \in [0,2]$ you have to add the probability that the client is served in t minutes, thus resulting in an integral.

Comment: RIGHT! Thank you man

Comment: If you are 100% sure that your problems is solved, you may consider accepting the answer.